# Как получить историю push в react router?

Tags: reactjs, redux, html5-history-api

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'
...
dispatch(push(path))
dispatch(push(path))
dispatch(push(path))
```

Как получить весь список того что было помещено в push?
То есть то что будет затем задаваться при нажатии на кнопку назад в браузере?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1496